# Google Sheet Script to send email only when specific range of cells are edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will notify certain people via email address only in the case when a certain cell range has been edited, say from C1 to D20. Any other changes outside that range should be ignored and not reported.

So far, i tried something like this, but its not working..

```
function processEdit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("System");
  var value = sheet.getRange("C1:D18").getValue();

  if (value == true){

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@domain.com",
    subject: "Test",
    body: "Changes have occurred in the System table."
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an installable on onEdit()

```
function processEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "System" && e.range.columnStart > 2 && e.range.columnStart < 5 && e.range.rowStart < 21 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //the rest is your code
    var value = sh.getRange("C1:D18").getValue();
    if (value == true) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "email@domain.com",
        subject: "Test",
        body: "Changes have occurred in the System table."
      });
    }
  }
}
```